# How to set auto increment value after deleting a middle row

Tags: php

I have a Table

```
id  paper_title
1   General English1
2   General English2
3   General English3
4   General English4
5   General English5
6   General English6
7   General English7
.
.
.
.
100 General English100.
```

Suppose If i delete row 4 and row 5, is it possible to update the id of General English6 And General English7 Set to 4,5 respectively and If i delete a row in middle or start the id should reset continuously like 1 2 3 4 5..................100.Please Help.

Comment: Why not add an is_deleted field and set it to "T" when you "delete" it?  Rather than having to go and loop through all rows that follow the deleted row and editing them.

Answer (score 1):

Determine the `id` of the row that you want to delete (let's call that id `$foo`). Then execute

```
UPDATE tbl SET id = id-1 WHERE id > $foo
```

get the highest `id` and call it `$max`:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM tbl
```

Then set the new auto increment value:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = $max+1
```

Do this for every row you delete. I sure hope `id` is not your primary key. And anyways, there is definitely a better solution to your underlying problem. There is usually no need to have the rows in a database table numbered from 1 to whatever without gaps.

Comment: + for "I sure hope id is not your primary key."

Comment: Sorry,i forgot to specify id is a primary key NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT.Please suggest me a way to solve the above problem

Comment: Primary keys should be [immutable](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/8187/should-a-primary-key-be-immutable). The sole purpose of a primary key is often, to uniquely identify records. For that purpose, they do not need to be consecutive. Primary keys usually do not come from the business domain and therefore do not have to fulfil any other constaints than beeing unique within a table. Such primary keys are called [surrogate keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key). I strongly suggest to familiarize yourself with this concept.